# Grab item prices from newegg

Tags: php, templates, curl, screen-scraping

Ok, i need to get the prices of items from newegg.com. I'm an affiliate with them and i have permission.

I want to get the prices using php scripts and then insert them into a template and save the page.

How do i get the prices, i tried cURL but it's really confusing.

Any help is appreciated.

[http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814150506&cm_sp=ProductSpotlight-*-14-150-506-*-07112011](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814150506&cm_sp=ProductSpotlight-_-14-150-506-_-07112011)

That's the item i tried doing it with.

Answer (score 6):

Read this post: http://www.bemasher.net/archives/1002

In that post it tells you to do:
 `http://www.ows.newegg.com/Products.egg/{Item Number}/Specification`

So in your case go to http://www.ows.newegg.com/Products.egg/N82E16814150506/Specification to get all the information you need.

Comment: Zoran,
User-Agent: Newegg

Answer (score 2):

You can get the price and availability from this link: http://www.newegg.com/Product/MappingPrice.aspx?Item=N82E16814150506

The Specification api will not tell you the availability information.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/bemasher/NeweggMobileAPI,

use

```
User-Agent: Newegg iPhone App / 4.4.0
```