# NewEgg API access for price, inventory (JSON/XML)

Tags: xml, json, api

can you provide me newegg api for update price OR inventory OR any of example something like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grab item prices from newegg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656029/grab-item-prices-from-newegg)

Answer (score 15):

## **SOLUTION!**

Berried inside [this](http://promotions.newegg.com/marketplace/sellers/resourceLibrary/Subscription%20Integration%20Guide.pdf) NewEgg document was a link to a [Newegg_Marketplace_API_DeveloperGuide.zip](https://sellerportal.newegg.com/Guideline/Newegg_Marketplace_API_DeveloperGuide.zip)

The .zip contains a 370 page 'NeweggMarketplaceAPIDeveloperGuide_V3.05.pdf'

That was hard to find.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of the JSON API that newegg mobile applications use:

http://www.bemasher.net/archives/1002

Comment: No idea whether the API still works, but you can access the wayback machine version https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20121204084322/http://bemasher.net/archives/1002/

Answer (score 2):

This may be a little late, but there is a Newegg API available from Newegg. The API does require some heavy lifting in developing your own client library, but it is well documented and thought out. I would suggest contacting newEgg for developer access.

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: @john Once I have a moment tomorrow at work ill post an update

Comment: @John Here is the link for the API documents: https://sellerportal.newegg.com/Guideline/Integration_Guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can get the price and availability from this link: http://www.newegg.com/Product/MappingPrice.aspx?Item=N82E16814150506

This is the simplest way to obtain the inventory information.

The Specification api (http://www.bemasher.net/archives/1002) will not tell you the availability information.

Answer (score 0):

[Newegg Marketplace API Developer Guide v3.07](http://lesovoz.by/misc/Newegg_Marketplace_API_Developer_Guide_v3.07/?page=1)

Answer (score -1):

Update price/inventory of single item:
https://developer.newegg.com/newegg_marketplace_api/item_management/

Batch mode:Inventory Update Feed and Price Update Feed:
https://developer.newegg.com/newegg_marketplace_api/datafeed_management/submit_feed/